# My inverse compositional homograhy image align cannot converge?

Tags: c++, computer-vision, robotics

I implement the algorithm based on [homographyTrackingDemo](https://github.com/albertoCrive/homographyTrackingDemo) and [LK-20-years](http://www.ncorr.com/download/publications/bakerunify.pdf). It's adaption of inverse compositional LK algorithm for estimating affine transformation. There are several steps I have tried:

1. Derive the derivative of template image;
2. Derive the derivative of homography transformation on template control points at identity transformation
3. Compute the Steepest Gradient Matrix and Hessian matrix

These steps are precomputed before stepping into iteration and we iterate:

1. Warp target image by homography
2. Compute the difference between warped target image and template image
3. Solve the linear equations and then update homography parameters

I hope some guy can give me a hint about whether my understanding about this algorithm is wrong. The c++ code is as follows:

```
AlignmentResults ICA::GaussNewtonMinimization(const StructOfArray2di & pixelsOnTemplate, const vector<Mat> & images, const vector<Mat> & templates, const OptimizationParameters optParam, vector<float> & parameters)
{
    AlignmentResults alignmentResults;
    alignmentResults.nIter = 0;
    alignmentResults.exitFlag = 1e6;

    //parameters must contain the initial guess. It is updated during optimization
    uint nChannels(images.size());
    vector<vector<float> > templatePixelIntensities(nChannels,vector<float>(pixelsOnTemplate.size()));//, templatePixelDx(nChannels,vector<float>(pixelsOnTemplate.size())), templatePixelDy(nChannels,vector<float>(pixelsOnTemplate.size()));
    vector<Mat> imageDx(nChannels), imageDy(nChannels);
    uint nParam = parameters.size();

    //vector<Eigen::Matrix<float, 2, N_PARAM>, Eigen::aligned_allocator<Eigen::Matrix<float, 2, N_PARAM> > > warpJacobians(pixelsOnTemplate.size());

    Eigen::MatrixXf sdImages(pixelsOnTemplate.size(), nParam);
    vector<float>  errorImage(pixelsOnTemplate.size(), 0.0);

    StructOfArray2di warpedPixels;
    Eigen::Matrix<float, N_PARAM, N_PARAM> hessian;
    Eigen::Matrix<float, N_PARAM, N_PARAM> hessianInv;
    hessian.setZero();


    std::vector<Eigen::Matrix<float, N_PARAM, N_PARAM>, Eigen::aligned_allocator<Eigen::Matrix<float, N_PARAM, N_PARAM>>> hessians(nChannels);
    std::vector<Eigen::MatrixXf> JacosT(nChannels);
    Eigen::Matrix<float, N_PARAM, 1> rhs;
    Eigen::Matrix<float, N_PARAM, 1> deltaParam;

    std::vector<float> zeroPara(8, 0.);
#pragma omp parallel for
    for(int iChannel = 0; iChannel<nChannels; ++iChannel)
    {
        ComputeImageDerivatives(templates[iChannel], imageDx[iChannel], imageDy[iChannel]);
        hessians[iChannel].setZero();
        JacosT[iChannel] = Eigen::MatrixXf(N_PARAM, pixelsOnTemplate.size());

        for(int iPoint = 0; iPoint < pixelsOnTemplate.size(); ++iPoint)
        {
            int pos = templates[iChannel].cols * pixelsOnTemplate.y[iPoint] + pixelsOnTemplate.x[iPoint];
            templatePixelIntensities[iChannel][iPoint] = ((float*)templates[iChannel].data)[pos];

            float Dx = ((float*)imageDx[iChannel].data)[pos];
            float Dy = ((float*)imageDy[iChannel].data)[pos];
            //printf("%f %f\n", Dx, Dy);
            Eigen::Matrix<float, 2, N_PARAM> warpJ;
            Homography::ComputeWarpJacobian(pixelsOnTemplate.x[iPoint], pixelsOnTemplate.y[iPoint], zeroPara, warpJ);
            //std::cout << warpJ << std::endl;
            Eigen::Matrix<float, 1, N_PARAM> J2H;
            Eigen::Matrix<float, 1, 2> ID;
            ID[0] = Dx;
            ID[1] = Dy;
            J2H = ID*warpJ;

            JacosT[iChannel].col(iPoint) = J2H.transpose();
            hessians[iChannel] += JacosT[iChannel].col(iPoint) * J2H;
        }
        hessian += hessians[iChannel];
    }

    while (alignmentResults.exitFlag == 1e6)
    {
        rhs.setZero();

        ComputeWarpedPixels(pixelsOnTemplate, parameters, warpedPixels);

#pragma omp parallel for
        for(int iChannel = 0; iChannel<images.size(); ++iChannel)
        {
            ComputeResiduals(images[iChannel], templatePixelIntensities[iChannel], warpedPixels, errorImage);
            for (int i = 0; i<nParam; ++i)
            {
                for(uint iPoint(0); iPoint<pixelsOnTemplate.size(); ++iPoint)
                {
                    float val = (errorImage[iPoint] == std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity() ? 0: errorImage[iPoint]); 
                    rhs(i,0) -= (JacosT[iChannel])(i, iPoint) * val;
                }
            }
        }


        deltaParam = hessian.fullPivLu().solve(rhs);

        std::vector<float> vDelta(8, 0.), invDelta(8, 0.);
        for(size_t i = 0; i<N_PARAM; ++i)
        {
            vDelta[i] = deltaParamd(i,0);
        }

        Homography::InverseWarpParameters(vDelta, invDelta);
        parameters = Homography::ParametersUpdateCompositional(parameters, invDelta);


        alignmentResults.poseIntermediateGuess.push_back(parameters);
        alignmentResults.residualNorm.push_back(ComputeResidualNorm(errorImage));
        if(alignmentResults.nIter > 0)
            alignmentResults.exitFlag = CheckConvergenceOptimization(deltaParam.norm(), alignmentResults.nIter, abs(alignmentResults.residualNorm[alignmentResults.nIter] - alignmentResults.residualNorm[alignmentResults.nIter-1]), optParam);
        alignmentResults.nIter++;

    return alignmentResults;
}
```

Comment: You should post your images, and visually show the initial solution and the final solution. This is an iterative optimization that can easily get stuck in a local minimum if your initial solution is far from the true solution.